# Winbind command for querying groups that a user is member of returns only few records

Tags: active-directory, samba

I have 10k groups (type being security group) in both win2008/win12 server for which a particular user (userX) is a member of. When I query the AD server trying

> wbinfo --user-sids=userXsid

I do not get all the 10k group sids while I get only 2052 of those. I tried searching why this happens, I couldn't find anything on this. I was thinking may be there is a limit for records being returned, but there is none that I see.

Answer (score 0):

Mabe you should check in `smb.conf`, and increase this values:

```
 idmap config *:range = 2000-3999
```

and increase this other parameters:

```
 winbind uid = 2000-3999
 winbind gid = 2000-3999
```